# JMeter - Changing a Cookie's Value during a Test?

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I have created a test plan in JMeter *(*Version 2.13)*. I was able to add a Cookie Manager to the plan and have my cookies preserved between HTTP Requests, which works just fine.

What I'm trying to do now is, if possible, preserve one Cookie from the start *(*Called "JSESSIONID")* and then have another Cookie *(*let's call it "MYID")* which can be modified **during** the test.

**My 1st try at this was like the following:**

```
+Thread Group
    -HTTP Request Defaults
    -HTTP Cookie Manager
    +HTTP Request - Goto HomePage
        -HTTP Cookie Manager - Set MYID="server_1"
    +HTTP Request - Load Login Page
        -HTTP Cookie Manager - Set MYID="server_2"
....and so on for about 3 more HTTP Requests....
```

But, doing it this way only kept the original Cookies which were captured by the initial Cookie Manager which was set right under the Thread Group element.

**Apache's site warns that:**

> "If there is more than one Cookie Manager in the scope of a Sampler, there is currently no way to specify which one is to be used. Also, a cookie stored in one cookie manager is not available to any other manager, so use multiple Cookie Managers with care."

Another test I did, that was similar to the first except I added a User Defined Variables element to the start of the test which had a variable for the MYID Cookie set to one server, and then about 2 or 3 HTTP Requests down I had a second User Defined Variables element, this time setting the variable to another server. But, after reading a bit more on the User Variables, JMeter only reads User Defined Variables ONCE, at the beginning of the test. So the variable I set last would remain as whatever I set it to in the 2nd User Defined Variables section. So that way won't work to change the Cookie value during the test...

I also, read this from ApacheJMeter's site, here [Using Variables to Parametrize Tests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#using_variables), which seems closest to what I am trying to achieve. But, from their example it seems as though it's for modifying variables before the test starts, like for example setting a variable from the command line...

**Summary:**
To sum things up, what I am trying to achieve is to send my HTTP Requests with 2 Cookies: 
    1. ***JSESSIONID***
    2. ***MYID***
Where *JSESSIONID* will remain the same from the very start, and *MYID* which I want to change it's value during test *(*multiple times if posible)*.

Let me know if that does not make sense and I will try and explain further.
Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Beanshell scripting for cookies manipulation as:

1. Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to your HTTP Request
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

   CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();

   for (int i = 0; i < manager.getCookieCount(); i++) {
     Cookie cookie = manager.get(i);        
     if (cookie.getName().equals("MYID")) {
           cookie.setValue(vars.get("foo"));
           manager.remove(i);
           manager.add(cookie);
           break;

     }

   }
   ```

Above code will substitute "MYID" cookie value with "foo" JMeter Variable value via direct calls to [CookieManager](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.html) class (see API documentation for all possible methods and fields)

Check out [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for advanced information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated!

I will give that a try and post back with my results.

Comment: So I add that to each "HTTP Request" element, is that right?

Comment: I keep seeing errors and warnings in the log viewer when I run my Test case. I am seeing the following:

Comment: `ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ''import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie; import org.apache.jmeter. . . . '' : Cannot access field: getCookieCount, on object: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager@30593b53

WARN  - Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ''import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie; import org.apache.jmeter. . . . '' : Cannot access field: getCookieCount, on object: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager@30593`

Comment: I apologize for the consecutive comments, but the errors went away. I had a `log.info("print some strings");` line in there and as soon as I removed it, the ERROR and WARN lines disappeared from the log viewer... Weird! And even weirder I had commented out that log.info() line way earlier in my testing, but it was still printing to the log. I was using "//" as the comment char. But, after deleting the log.info() line that was commented out, the errors stopped showing.

Comment: Dimitri, hopefully you will see this comment... Quick Question, I wanted to try and use some of this code in a BeanShell PostProcessor, but when I run the Test Plan I get an error saying _"Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getCookieManager() on undefined variable or class name: sampler"_... Is there a way to use "sampler" in a PostProcessor?

Comment: Hi Matt. I believe I have answered it there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29914496/2897748