# JMeter - Verify a Specific Cookie Value was Used?

Tags: cookies, jmeter, beanshell

So in my Test Plan I have a Cookie Manager setup inside my Thread Group which sets a specific Cookie value for 1 Cookie. Let's call it, ***MYID***. I'm trying to figure out a way to verify that this specific Cookie's value was used to complete this one HTTP Request, because if I set my MYID to a specific value *(*which actually tells which web server to go to)*, say to *"Server1"*, but *Server1* is down, unavailable, etc... HAProxy should change this and send you to *Server2*.

So basically I want to try and make sure that Cookie ***MYID*** was equal to ***"Server1"*** all the way through the HTTP Request.

I am trying to use a BeanShell PostProcessor to verify the Cookie's value after the request is ran, but when I tried using some code I have inside a PreProcessor that sets a cookie in a different Test Plan of mine I get an error saying:

**Error Message:**

> Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getCookieManager() on undefined variable or class name: sampler

And below here is the Code slightly modified from a BeanShell PreProcessor in another Test Plan I have...

**CODE:**

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();

for (int i = 0; i < manager.getCookieCount(); i++) {
    Cookie cookie = manager.get(i);
    if (cookie.getName().equals("MYID"))    {
        if (cookie.getValue().equals("Server1")) {
            log.info("OK: The Cookie contained the Correct Server Number...");
        } else {
            log.info("ERROR: The Cookie did NOT contain the Correct Server Number...");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

For the error, I was thinking the "sampler" object was no longer available since the Request was already run, or something along those lines, but I'm not sure...

Or, is there another JMeter object I should be using instead of the "BeanShell PostProcessor" in order to verify the Cookie's value was correct..?

Any thoughts or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trying to get cookie manager from the parent sampler in the Beanshell **PostProcessor** - you need to use **ctx.getCurrentSampler()**, not "sampler" as it is not exposed in script variables.

So just change this line:

```
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
```

to

```
 CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();
```

And your script should start working as you expect.

`ctx` is a shorthand to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) instance and `getCurrentSampler()` method name is self-explanatory.

For more information on Beanshell scripting check out [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks AGAIN Dmitri!!